# Bukkit equalsIgnoreCase("gm 1") not working

Tags: java

I am trying to have a command /gm 1 to change the players gamemode to gamemode 1. I know there is a plugin called essentials out there that has that command but I am trying to practice building bukkit plugins. 
So here is my Main.java:

```
if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("gm 1")){
   String gm1 =  "gamemode 1 " + player.getName();
   Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), gm1);
   player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "Your now in Creative Mode.");   
}
```

Plugin.yml:

```
commands:
   gm 1:
     description: Sets your game mode to creative.
```

I am pretty new to java can someone help?

Comment: Your problem is `cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("gm 1")` is not true? Printout cmd.getName to check if it's really equals

Comment: To rule out a potential NPE, swap the order of your `equalsIgnoreCase`, so it reads `"gm 1".equalsIgnoreCase(cmd.getName())`.

Comment: I tried yours Makoto and I get a syntax error

Comment: Post the updated code, and what `cmd.getName()` returns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `cmd.getName()` only returns the very first part of the command. (Here being `gm`). The `1` would be stored as `args[0]` because every word after the first is stored as a separate string in the `args` variable.
You want something more like:

```
if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("gm") && args[0] == "1"){
   String gm1 =  "gamemode 1 " + player.getName();
   Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), gm1);
   player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "You're now in Creative Mode.");   
}
```

And

```
commands:
  gm:
    description: Sets your game mode to creative.
```

Because, as above, the command is just `gm`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String arg2, String[] args) {
    Player p = (Player)sender;
    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("build")) {
        if(p.hasPermission("server.build")) {
            if(args.length < 0) {
                p.sendMessage(Main.p + " §cBitte benutze /build [on] [off]");
            }else {
                if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("on")) {
                    p.setGameMode(GameMode.CREATIVE);
                    p.sendMessage(Main.p + " §aDu hast den §eBuild-Modus §aAktiviert");
                    p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.BAT_DEATH, 10, 10);
                }else if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("off")) {
                    p.setGameMode(GameMode.SURVIVAL);
                    p.sendMessage(Main.p + " §cDu hast den §eBuild-Modus §cDeaktiviert");
                    p.setHealth(20);
                    p.setFoodLevel(20);
                    p.playSound(p.getLocation(), Sound.BAT_DEATH, 10, 10);
                }else {
                    p.sendMessage(Main.p + " §cBitte benutze /build [on] [off]");
                }
            }
        }else {
            p.sendMessage(Main.p + " §cDu hast keine Rechte §8| §aBewerbe dich doch auf ...");
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```